# Use RequireJS with Angular throws out exception

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, requirejs, frontend

I'm using RequireJS to load AngularJS controller to serve my frontend html.
However even though all the required libs are loaded, it throws out exception:

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module metaapp due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'metaapp' is not available!
```

Can anyone point me out of way?

Here is my directory structure:

[image: Directory Structure]

metacontroller.js:

```
/*global define*/
'use strict';

define(['angular'], function(angular){
  return ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.test = "haha";
  }
  ];
});
```

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-framework="angularjs">
  <head>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="metaapp" ng-controller="MetaController">
    {{test}}
    <script data-main="js/main" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
  </body> 
</html>
```

app.js

```
/*global require*/
'use strict';

require([
    'angular'
], function (angular) {
    require([
      'app/UserMeta/metacontroller',
      'app/UserMeta/metaservice'

    ], function (metaCtrl, metaSrv) {
      var app = angular.module('metaapp', []);
      app.controller('MetaController', metaCtrl);
    }); 
});
```

main.js

```
/*global require*/
'use strict';


require.config({
    paths: {
        angular: 'lib/angular'
    },
    shim: {
        angular: {
            exports: 'angular'
        }
    },
    deps: ['app']
});
```

[image: network in console]

-------------First update-----------------
update the controller  - replace scope with $scope.

-------------Second update----------------
In `app.js`, remove the dependencies injection. However still not working...

Errors:

`angular.js:63 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module metaapp due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'metaapp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument`

----------------------Update 3--------------------
ok, I figure it out...
I missed this line of code: `angular.bootstrap(document, ['metaapp']);` now it's working because I can see the `haha` interpreted on html page. 
However I still can see the errors, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the two nested modules behave.
Can they be merged to one?

```
/*global require*/
'use strict';

require([
  'angular',
  'app/UserMeta/metacontroller',
  'app/UserMeta/metaservice'

], function (angular, metaCtrl, metaSrv) {
  var app = angular.module('metaapp', [metaCtrl, metaSrv]);
  app.controller('MetaController', metaCtrl);
});
```

Comment: `var app = angular.module('metaapp', []);
  app.controller('MetaController', metaCtrl);` -- just tried this out, not working... ;-(

Comment: `angular.js:63 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module metaapp due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'metaapp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument`